# Is it possible for reset (actionButton) and submitButton to work independently in Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have a reset (`actionButton`) and update button (`submitButton`) in my Shiny app. The problem is that to reset the app, I have to click on the `reset` button followed by the `update` button. Is it possible to reset the app without having to click on update?

**EDIT**: I do want the app to update only after the user explicitly clicks update. This is because in my app they will have the option to select several selectors to filter the data. Happy to use something else other than `submitbutton`, but so far this has been the only function that worked for the purpose.

In the example below, I have to click on `update` **twice** to get the whole app to reset :

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    numericInput("num", label = "Make changes", value = 1),
    submitButton("Update", icon("refresh")),
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
    helpText(
      "When you click the button above, you should see",
      "the output below update to reflect the value you",
      "entered at the top:"
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    # submit buttons do not have a value of their own,
    # they control when the app accesses values of other widgets.
    # input$num is the value of the number widget.
    output$value <- renderPrint({
      input$num
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$reset, {
      shinyjs::reset("num")
    })
    
  }
)
```

I hope someone can enlighten me!

Comment: Apps that include a submit button do not automatically update their outputs when inputs change, rather they wait until the user explicitly clicks the submit button. The use of `submitButton` is generally discouraged in favor of the more versatile `actionButton()`

Comment: Thanks for that, [I read this on the Shiny app site](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/submitButton.html), but this is exactly what i want; I want to choose several filters before I click on update because the app is already slow, so I don't want it to react every time we select a filter.

Comment: Agreed with @YBS, avoid `submitButton` if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `actionButton` in combination with `updateNumericInput()` will meet your needs.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    numericInput("num", label = "Make changes", value = 1),
    actionButton("Update",  "refresh"),
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
    helpText(
      "When you click the button above, you should see",
      "the output below update to reflect the value you",
      "entered at the top:"
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    
    # submit buttons do not have a value of their own,
    # they control when the app accesses values of other widgets.
    # input$num is the value of the number widget. 
    
    
    observeEvent(input$Update, {
      output$value <- renderPrint({
        isolate(input$num)
      })
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$reset, {
      #shinyjs::reset("num")
      updateNumericInput(session,"num",value=1)
      
    })
    
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but it doesn't work for my app, unfortunately...